# What's the correct preposition to use when describing the aspect ratio of a screen?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm referring specifically to aspect ratios of TV screens.

A common aspect ratio of a TV screen is 16:9. Would this be pronounced "sixteen to nine" or "sixteen by nine"?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer, colloquially, "sixteen **by** nine' (although "sixteen to nine" is also clear, grammatical, and only very briefly likely to be confused with a time of day).

Majenko's answer argued that using "by" implies there must be "units", for example "inches" (and that, because there are no units, therefore "by" is incorrect).

In response to that I would counter-argue that "by" implies a "ratio", and that a ratio can be (and, in this case, is) a "[dimensionless quantity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity)" which requires no specific units.

> In dimensional analysis, a dimensionless quantity or quantity of dimension one is a quantity without an associated physical dimension. It is thus a "pure" number, etc.
>
> Dimensionless quantities are often defined as products or ratios of quantities that are not dimensionless, but whose dimensions cancel out when their powers are multiplied. etc.

For example, a rectangle which is "nine by seven" is so, no matter whether we're talking about "nine by seven metres" or ""nine by seven inches" or even "nine by seven pixels".

Comment: I follow your logic, but differ with you on the idiomaticity of your preferred preposition. Take the common case of a legislative vote, where the differential counts for and against a proposed measure are also expressed as a ratio: I doubt that even you would describe the result by saying something as unidiomatic as "The proponents of the measure won by 57 **by** 43 votes". Yet the logic of your argument is the same when you are considering  the ratio of winning to losing votes as it is when considering the ratio of horizontal to vertical units to describe the shape of a screen.

Comment: @ErikKowal I'd say that 57 to 43 is not a ratio: it's a difference, i.e. it's a subtraction not a division. In the case of voting, what matters is the difference i.e. that they won by 14 votes. Anoher way to say that would be "57 versus 43" or "57 against 43".

Comment: Well, it is both a ratio *and* a difference, isn't it? And when the outcome is described as I implied above (i.e. "The proponents of the measure won by 57 **to** 43"), the focus is on the ratio, not the difference. As you have already indicated in your own comment, it is when you describe the outcome as the *difference* in the vote totals (making **that** the focus) that you would use *by*: "The proponents of the measure won **by** 14 votes".

Comment: OP asks about TV aspect ratio specifically and 16 *by* 9 is the traditional way to express this ratio. Although Wikipedia states that "16 9" and "16 to 9" are also used, in my experience (I have done professional TV color calibrations for many years) "16 by 9" is most prevalent.

Comment: @Jim So you agree with my answer.

Comment: This has its origins in still photography’s actual film dimensions. Large-format film was in actual dimensions, so 4×5″, 5×7″, 8×10″ (more rarely 11×14″, 16×20″, 20×24″). Even the smaller 120 film used in medium-format photography, now expressed in cm instead of inches, followed the same route: 6×4.5 cm (called “645”), 6×6 cm, 6×7 cm, 6×9 cm. Tiny small-format’s 135 film was 36×24 mm, but those numbers are inconveniently large, leading to **the *aspect* ratio 3:2** being favored over 1½×1″. 3:4 sensors make 4×5⅓″ prints, 9:16 make 4½×8″ prints, etc. People like convenient numbers.

Answer (score -2):

Sixteen *to* nine, since it is a ratio, not an absolute set of dimensions.  Sixteen *by* nine implies a set of exact units that are unmentioned, such as *sixteen by nine inches*.

It can also be said as sixteen *in* nine, especially when representing a gradient, such as the steepness of a road.  A 10:1 rise would be a rise of 1 unit for every 10 units travelled forwards.

In a ratio the units are undefined and meaningless, since it can be applied equally to any units of any size and still have the same meaning.

It can be expanded out to: "Sixteen of these *compared to* nine of those".

For further clarification, consider a photograph.  For many years, before photography went digital and people stopped having all their photographs on paper the most common size of a normal photograph was 6 inches wide and 4 inches high.  The accepted "default" unit of measurement of photographs was the inch, so they were commonly known as "6 by 4 prints".  They imply that the default units, the inch, are there but not shown.  It is an exact size.

That size, however, is not shown as 6:4, but as 6x4; the "x" implying the word "by" not "to".  Also, the aspect ratio, while it could (incorrectly) be written as 6:4, should actually be written as 3:2.  Ratios, as they define a relationship between two other values, should be written as the lowest integer value pair.

Another case in point is the votes mentioned in the comments to the other answer.  Person A had 57 votes, and Person B had 43 votes.  As it happens 43 is a prime number, so cannot be divided any lower, and so is the lowest integer pair already (thanks for a great example guys).  So both the ratio and the quantity are 57 to 43.  The word "to" is used for the quantity instead of "by" in this case because the two values are *opposing* values.  "The vote was 57 to A *as opposed to* 43 for B".

The ratio, however, will always be 57:43 regardless of the number of votes cast.  If 500 people voted, and they voted in the same proportions, the number of votes would be 285 to 215, with a vote difference of 70.  The ratio of votes is still 57:43.  For every 57 people that voted for A 43 will have voted for B.

There is no implied quantity, so there can be no "by", only a relationship between two other quantities.

Sometimes you see ratios written with the values divided right down so what would be the numerator in a fraction would be 1, and the denominator a decimal value.  In the case of the 16:9 screen this could also be written as 1.778:1.  It can be easier to calculate a real size from this pair of values, since if you have a screen that is 25 inches high, it must be 25 × 1.778 inches high, or 44.44 inches.

Mathematically, however, this method is frowned upon since in this example the .1778 is actually a recurring number and is 1.777777... Using 1.778:1 truncates that number and reduces the accuracy of any calculations.  Keeping the ratio as 16:9, and hence all sums using the fraction 16/9, keeps all calculations more precise.

There is only one case where having a TV screen of "16 by 9" is actually valid, and that is when you have an 18.35" screen, where the X and Y dimensions are actually 16 inches and 9 inches respectively.

The use of the word "by" also stems from multiplying "X by Y" to find the area, so a screen of "16 by 9" would have an "area of 144 square inches".  That can only hold true if the 16 and the 9 refer to inches, which is only the case for the 18.35" screen. It cannot hold true for any other size screen.

Here is a quote from Sky in a document describing what widescreen is:

> The term “widescreen” is used to describe the format in which the picture is broadcast and displayed. Widescreen
>   is considered to give a better viewing experience as it closely resembles the way the human eye views the world -
>   enhancing the sense of realism. The ratio of the width to the height of a widescreen TV picture is 16 to 9 and is often
>   called ‘16:9 format’.
>
> *-- [Sky: Understanding Widescreen TV](http://www.skybusiness.co.nz/Portals/2/Understanding%20Widescreen.pdf) (pdf)*

In the whole document the word "by" occurs only the once.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a perfectly reasonable answer.

Comment: @ErikKowal I didn't downvote it but I disagreed with it so I posted a competing/alternate answer.

Comment: "There is only one case where having a TV screen of "16 by 9" is actually valid, and that is when you have an 18.35" screen, where the X and Y dimensions are actually 16 inches and 9 inches respectively." But the question was about the aspect ratio, not a screen. Professional usage strongly favors "by" here, regardless of what may be proper in other contexts.

Comment: I'm sorry, I disagree.  20 years in IT, and now I design and build TFT systems, and never have I heard "by" used for an aspect ratio, and I have never used "by" for an aspect ratio.  For the pixel dimensions (640 by 480) yes, but not "16 by 9".  Ever. Period.   Are you AmE or BrE? Maybe this is an "across the pond" difference.

Comment: Jim's American, you're British (I'm Canadian). https://www.google.com/search?q=%2216+by+9%22 returns 280,000 results. https://www.google.com/search?q=%2216+to+9%22 returns 348,000 results, BUT the former results are about the aspect ratio whereas the latter results seem to be mostly other topics.

Comment: On my results most of the first page of the former results are about the "16 by 9 film collective" whomever they may be - nothing to do with any aspect ratio.  There's more hits on the first page for the aspect ratio for the second search.

Comment: And of course we all know that whatever google or wikipedia say are gospel truth.  I have added a quote from a document by Sky - people who know a thing or two about TV pictures.

Comment: And while we're counting google results:  The query *aspect "16 by 9"* returns 43,500 results.  The query *aspect "16 to 9"* returns 308,000 results.  *To* wins, hands down.

Comment: @Majenko -- the "16 by 9 film collective" is referring (indirectly) to the aspect ratio, but you're right, "by" invariable refers to fixed unit; "to" to ratios.